# Configure Nginx as Reverse Proxy with Apache2 on CentOS7 enabled with SELinux

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, reverse-proxy, selinux, centos7

I'm working on a project for academic purposes, the goal is to use Nginx as a Reverse Proxy for Apache, so far i've installed Nginx and everything is ok, it's listening to port 80, but when i was going to installed apache it says that its already installed with latest updates, but when i'm trying to set up an Apache Server on a CentOS 7 machine i am not seeing the Apache test page when I get visit my machines IP Address.

I've tried to start the service with **`service httpd start`** but this is the output:

> Job for httpd.service failed. See 'systemctl status httpd.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.

then runned this **`systemctl status httpd.service`** and this is the output:

```
    httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2015-02-02 16:01:26 CST; 52s ago
  Process: 21061 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 21057 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 21057 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Feb 02 16:01:26 localhost.localdomain httpd[21057]: AH00558: httpd: Could not...
Feb 02 16:01:26 localhost.localdomain httpd[21057]: (13)Permission denied: AH...
Feb 02 16:01:26 localhost.localdomain httpd[21057]: (13)Permission denied: AH...
Feb 02 16:01:26 localhost.localdomain httpd[21057]: no listening sockets avai...
Feb 02 16:01:26 localhost.localdomain httpd[21057]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
Feb 02 16:01:26 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process...
Feb 02 16:01:26 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache ...
Feb 02 16:01:26 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered ...
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Then runned this **`journalctl -xn`** and this is the output:

```
-- Logs begin at Mon 2015-02-02 12:10:31 CST, end at Mon 2015-02-02 16:10:01 CST
Feb 02 16:01:58 localhost.localdomain setroubleshoot[21059]: received signal=14
Feb 02 16:01:58 localhost.localdomain setroubleshoot[21059]: KeyboardInterrupt i
Feb 02 16:01:58 localhost.localdomain setroubleshoot[21059]: writing database (/
Feb 02 16:01:58 localhost.localdomain dbus-daemon[935]: 'list' object has no att
Feb 02 16:02:28 localhost.localdomain gnome-session[8273]: [8917:8954:0202/16022
Feb 02 16:02:29 localhost.localdomain gnome-session[8273]: Fontconfig error: Can
Feb 02 16:10:01 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Created slice user-0.slice.
-- Subject: Unit user-0.slice has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit user-0.slice has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Feb 02 16:10:01 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Session 48 of user ro
-- Subject: Unit session-48.scope has begun with start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit session-48.scope has begun starting up.
Feb 02 16:10:01 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started Session 48 of user roo
-- Subject: Unit session-48.scope has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit session-48.scope has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Feb 02 16:10:01 localhost.localdomain CROND[21247]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa
```

**Configuration**

*Nginx*

```
    # For more information on configuration, see:
    #   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
    #   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

    user  nginx;
    worker_processes  1;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    #error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
    #error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

    pid        /run/nginx.pid;


    events {
        worker_connections  1024;
    }


    http {
        include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type  application/octet-stream;

        log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                          '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                          '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

        sendfile        on;
        #tcp_nopush     on;
    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    index   index.html index.htm;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
server {
     listen  80;

        root /var/www/;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name example.com;

        location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:80;

         }
}
}
```

*Apache2*

```
  #
# This is the main Apache HTTP server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/> for detailed information.
# In particular, see 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/directives.html>
# for a discussion of each configuration directive.
#
# Do NOT simply read the instructions in here without understanding
# what they do.  They're here only as hints or reminders.  If you are unsure
# consult the online docs. You have been warned.  
#
# Configuration and logfile names: If the filenames you specify for many
# of the server's control files begin with "/" (or "drive:/" for Win32), the
# server will use that explicit path.  If the filenames do *not* begin
# with "/", the value of ServerRoot is prepended -- so 'log/access_log'
# with ServerRoot set to '/www' will be interpreted by the
# server as '/www/log/access_log', where as '/log/access_log' will be
# interpreted as '/log/access_log'.

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# Do not add a slash at the end of the directory path.  If you point
# ServerRoot at a non-local disk, be sure to specify a local disk on the
# Mutex directive, if file-based mutexes are used.  If you wish to share the
# same ServerRoot for multiple httpd daemons, you will need to change at
# least PidFile.
#
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"

#
# Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
# ports, instead of the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
# directive.
#
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
#
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 8000

#
# Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) Support
#
# To be able to use the functionality of a module which was built as a DSO you
# have to place corresponding `LoadModule' lines at this location so the
# directives contained in it are actually available _before_ they are used.
# Statically compiled modules (those listed by `httpd -l') do not need
# to be loaded here.
#
# Example:
# LoadModule foo_module modules/mod_foo.so
#
Include conf.modules.d/*.conf

#
# If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
# httpd as root initially and it will switch.  
#
# User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
# It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
# running httpd, as with most system services.
#
User apache
Group apache

# 'Main' server configuration
#
# The directives in this section set up the values used by the 'main'
# server, which responds to any requests that aren't handled by a
# <VirtualHost> definition.  These values also provide defaults for
# any <VirtualHost> containers you may define later in the file.
#
# All of these directives may appear inside <VirtualHost> containers,
# in which case these default settings will be overridden for the
# virtual host being defined.
#

#
# ServerAdmin: Your address, where problems with the server should be
# e-mailed.  This address appears on some server-generated pages, such
# as error documents.  e.g. admin@your-domain.com
#
ServerAdmin root@localhost

#
# ServerName gives the name and port that the server uses to identify itself.
# This can often be determined automatically, but we recommend you specify
# it explicitly to prevent problems during startup.
#
# If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
#
#ServerName www.example.com:80

#
# Deny access to the entirety of your server's filesystem. You must
# explicitly permit access to web content directories in other 
# <Directory> blocks below.
#
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

#
# Note that from this point forward you must specifically allow
# particular features to be enabled - so if something's not working as
# you might expect, make sure that you have specifically enabled it
# below.
#

#
# DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
# documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
# symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
#
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

#
# Relax access to content within /var/www.
#
<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# Further relax access to the default document root:
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride None

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#
# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
# is requested.
#
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being 
# viewed by Web clients. 
#
<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

#
# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog "logs/error_log"

#
# LogLevel: Control the number of messages logged to the error_log.
# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
#
LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    #
    # The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
    # a CustomLog directive (see below).
    #
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      # You need to enable mod_logio.c to use %I and %O
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    #
    # The location and format of the access logfile (Common Logfile Format).
    # If you do not define any access logfiles within a <VirtualHost>
    # container, they will be logged here.  Contrariwise, if you *do*
    # define per-<VirtualHost> access logfiles, transactions will be
    # logged therein and *not* in this file.
    #
    #CustomLog "logs/access_log" common

    #
    # If you prefer a logfile with access, agent, and referer information
    # (Combined Logfile Format) you can use the following directive.
    #
    CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    #
    # Redirect: Allows you to tell clients about documents that used to 
    # exist in your server's namespace, but do not anymore. The client 
    # will make a new request for the document at its new location.
    # Example:
    # Redirect permanent /foo http://www.example.com/bar

    #
    # Alias: Maps web paths into filesystem paths and is used to
    # access content that does not live under the DocumentRoot.
    # Example:
    # Alias /webpath /full/filesystem/path
    #
    # If you include a trailing / on /webpath then the server will
    # require it to be present in the URL.  You will also likely
    # need to provide a <Directory> section to allow access to
    # the filesystem path.

    #
    # ScriptAlias: This controls which directories contain server scripts. 
    # ScriptAliases are essentially the same as Aliases, except that
    # documents in the target directory are treated as applications and
    # run by the server when requested rather than as documents sent to the
    # client.  The same rules about trailing "/" apply to ScriptAlias
    # directives as to Alias.
    #
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"

</IfModule>

#
# "/var/www/cgi-bin" should be changed to whatever your ScriptAliased
# CGI directory exists, if you have that configured.
#
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>
    #
    # TypesConfig points to the file containing the list of mappings from
    # filename extension to MIME-type.
    #
    TypesConfig /etc/mime.types

    #
    # AddType allows you to add to or override the MIME configuration
    # file specified in TypesConfig for specific file types.
    #
    #AddType application/x-gzip .tgz
    #
    # AddEncoding allows you to have certain browsers uncompress
    # information on the fly. Note: Not all browsers support this.
    #
    #AddEncoding x-compress .Z
    #AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz
    #
    # If the AddEncoding directives above are commented-out, then you
    # probably should define those extensions to indicate media types:
    #
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

    #
    # AddHandler allows you to map certain file extensions to "handlers":
    # actions unrelated to filetype. These can be either built into the server
    # or added with the Action directive (see below)
    #
    # To use CGI scripts outside of ScriptAliased directories:
    # (You will also need to add "ExecCGI" to the "Options" directive.)
    #
    #AddHandler cgi-script .cgi

    # For type maps (negotiated resources):
    #AddHandler type-map var

    #
    # Filters allow you to process content before it is sent to the client.
    #
    # To parse .shtml files for server-side includes (SSI):
    # (You will also need to add "Includes" to the "Options" directive.)
    #
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

#
# Specify a default charset for all content served; this enables
# interpretation of all content as UTF-8 by default.  To use the 
# default browser choice (ISO-8859-1), or to allow the META tags
# in HTML content to override this choice, comment out this
# directive:
#
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mime_magic_module>
    #
    # The mod_mime_magic module allows the server to use various hints from the
    # contents of the file itself to determine its type.  The MIMEMagicFile
    # directive tells the module where the hint definitions are located.
    #
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>

#
# Customizable error responses come in three flavors:
# 1) plain text 2) local redirects 3) external redirects
#
# Some examples:
#ErrorDocument 500 "The server made a boo boo."
#ErrorDocument 404 /missing.html
#ErrorDocument 404 "/cgi-bin/missing_handler.pl"
#ErrorDocument 402 http://www.example.com/subscription_info.html
#

#
# EnableMMAP and EnableSendfile: On systems that support it, 
# memory-mapping or the sendfile syscall may be used to deliver
# files.  This usually improves server performance, but must
# be turned off when serving from networked-mounted 
# filesystems or if support for these functions is otherwise
# broken on your system.
# Defaults if commented: EnableMMAP On, EnableSendfile Off
#
#EnableMMAP off
EnableSendfile on

# Supplemental configuration
#
# Load config files in the "/etc/httpd/conf.d" directory, if any.
IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
```

Comment: @utrecht It's a project i'm working on for academic purposes, the goal is to use Nginx as a Reverse Proxy for Apache

Comment: How did you configure Apache?

Comment: @utrecht How do i do that?

Comment: @MichaelHampton i haven't configured Apache since it is preinstalled by Centos 7

Comment: No, that's what i'm doing right now, sorry

Comment: I think you will [find your answer here](http://serverfault.com/a/490183/126632).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the configuration snippets are missing it looks like that there is a port conflict. By default Apache2 and Nginx are listening on port 80. Check the logs. If there is a conflict, change the Listen port of Apache2 or Nginx to a port that is available.

The provided logs indicate the following:

```
Feb 02 16:01:26 localhost.localdomain httpd[21057]: no listening sockets avai...
```

This could mean that there is a port conflict indeed.

In order to solve this issue the default listen port that resides in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` should be changed to an available port and the httpd service should be restarted.

Change `Listen 80` to `Listen <available_port>`.

Regarding the log snippet provided in the comments:

`SELinux is preventing /usr/sbin/httpd from name_bind access on the tcp_socket .`

According [this documentation](http://drupalwatchdog.com/volume-2/issue-2/using-apache-and-selinux-together) this issue could be solved by executing `semanage port -a -t http_port_t -p tcp <apache2 port>` and restarting apache2. Note to [verify whether access to the port has been permitted](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux) using `semanage port -l`.

Comment: I'll try this out, post updated with the snippets

Comment: Still  get this message when trying to start the service _"Job for httpd.service failed. See 'systemctl status httpd.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
"_

Comment: Yeah, it does return nothing, and no Apache does not start even if nginx  is stoped

Comment: Something Wierd happened, i set the port to 8000, stoped nginx and try to start Apache and got this message: _"SELinux is preventing /usr/sbin/httpd from name_bind access on the tcp_socket ."_

Comment: Something i haven't telled is that i followed [this guide](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/SecuringSSH?highlight=%28network%29)   not sure if it has anything to do with the problem

Comment: What u mean by test system?

Comment: I see, i change the default port to "Use a Non-Standard Port" and i didn't realize that i had to tell SElinux about it, i'll try to fix it, but i've   got a question... if i set a Non-Standard Port, do i have to set apache to that port? for example if i set 2015 as my Non-Standard port, is that the port that i'll set to Apache?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20779/discussion-between-nonexistent-and-utrecht).

Answer (score 0):

the easiest thing to do is to turn selinux off, configure it all working then install audit2allow on the box. Turn SELinux back on and run audit2allow.

```
cat /var/log/audit/audit.log | grep AVC
```

formulate a policy based on the deny messages using

```
cat /var/log/audit/audit.log | grep AVC | audit2allow -m nginx
```

use -M to build the policy